# JSON_CONTAINS across tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a sort of social network for my school.

There are two tables in the database there are two tables:

- `users`, which contains (varchar) `username` and (json) `friends`—which contains a list of usernames that the user is friends with—and
- `posts`, which contains the (varchar) `publisher` field.

How can I write a query which returns all posts where the publisher is friends with a given user?

[image]

Post example:

```
| id  | publisher  | originalPublisher | postdate   | content                                                                       | likes |
| 113 | pvaqueiroz | NULL              | 2017-03-13 | {"contentType":"text","content":"DAB \\o\\","attatchments":[]} |     0 |
```

User example:

```
| id | username   | password                         | email                | fullname      | likes                                         | friends                                               | profpic                                                 |
|  1 | pvaqueiroz | 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b | pvaqueiroz@gmail.com | Paulo Queiroz | [31, 30, 0, 63, 68, 85, 89, 91, 92, 109, 114] | ["hacker", "girassol_l", "Dment", "Leel", "Mr Dibre"] | /carlos/posts_res/d11109ac342482457f87611483d661a6.jpeg |
```

Comment: Added a picture with both schemas

Comment: Please, just a sample of your json fields.

Comment: That is not a php question. What did you try?

Comment: I already found a solution in PHP but it sucks! I get all the posts and check one by one if the publisher is friends with the user. But now I need to use OFFSET and LIMIT on my query and I'm not doing that in PHP

Comment: Try classic m2m setup. Add friends table that has 2 IDs from user table follower_id and fallowing_id. If you want to store it as json you picked wrong db and structure.

Comment: You mean I should move back to MongoDB right?

Comment: "m2m" means "many-to-many", it's a relational database term. There's no reason to go back to MongoDB just because of this little issue. Break out your JSON as first-class columns that can be properly indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the right solution.

Create statements(skipping fields as they not required for explanation)

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_posts_1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_posts_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `friend_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_friend_idx` (`user_id` ASC, `friend_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_friends_f_users_idx` (`friend_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_friends_u_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_friends_f_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Every time you add a fried to a user you would just record a pair of ids in `friends` table

And queries will be:

```
-- Selecting user friends
SELECT * FROM friends f 
JOIN users u ON u.id = f.friend_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1 -- Id of user you need friends for

-- Selecting friends posts
SELECT * FROM friends f 
JOIN posts p ON p.user_id = f.friend_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1 -- Id of user you need friends' posts for
```

Comment: Thanks a for your answer, it works perfectly. I'm sorry bothering with this stupid question, but I was worried about the size of the friends table, I mean.. isn't it going to explode after a while?

Comment: @PauloQueiroz Makes no difference. This is going to be a small easy and fast table. Up to 50-80 million rows on a good hardware there will be no difference in speed. Way before that you will start getting issues with other queries and would have to start using cache(Memcached, Redis). As well as you can look in to sharding if your version of MySQL is 5.1+

Comment: I see.. Would you recommend me changing `ON DELETE NO ACTION` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: @PauloQueiroz Deleting is a very expensive operation for big tables and it can corrupt your data. It is better to just have a bool field deleted (in user table) and just mark records. On smaller applications `ON DELETE CASCADE` is a totally valid option.